# When using netbeans with php in the console; How to follow the "called in" part of a warning?

Tags: php, netbeans, hyperlink, console, warnings

A warning in the console can be clicked, but it takes me definition of the function that is called. Instead of taking me to the code from which the code is called.
I'm receiving the warning because I'm not passing enough arguments.